# How to set up a remote database?

Tags: ios, mysql, swift, database

I'm a beginner in swift iOS development and I'm enrolled in a couple of Udemy courses (Swift) although there is one question that I have that I can't seem to find the answer to. Bare in mind that I'm a beginner.

I want to make an app and a website that both use the same online database. Basically I want my users to be able to have their own account and store data on a remote database then be able to access it from either the app or the website.

How can I do that ? Most of the courses I followed suggest Firebase but I don't know how scalable it is, if it's fast enough and if it's not too expansive (I plan on having at least 10 000 users)

What would be the best option ? Should I use a MySQL and PHP alongside my swift app ? Should I stick to Firebase ? Or do you have any other suggestion ?

In my mind the best option would be to use Core Data and then synchronizing it with my database, but how do I do it ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: My personal suggestion is you create an API using NodeJS and this API communicaties with your MySQL database. From your app you do calls to the API using Alamofire.

Comment: @Mar-k is right, it's a matter of preference what your API language could be. I went with Firebase previously and regret it now, due to the restrictions if you want to expand to the web. I now made a API based on Ruby on Rails (via Heroku) and it was easier than I thought.

Comment: @TomWolters Which restrictions did make you regret? I am just thinking of switching _to_ firebase, so I am curious.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the replies. Do you know where I can find a tutorial or course about creating my own API ?

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer your questions one by one.

1. Is firebase scalable?
   Yes, you can scale it very easily. It supports up to 100,000+ simultaneous connections. Since you are hoping to have 10,000 users only few might be online simultaneously. So it will definitely work for you.
   For more info read https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebase-talk/KwN4vN7DxfQ/dgduFFZ8DAAJ
2. Is firebase fast?
   One of the reasons why firebase became popular is because it has a very good response time. Now that it is bought by Google, you don't need to worry about it at all.
3. How expensive is it?
   At 10,000 users you might end up spending 0-25$ if you use firebase. Google also gives free credits for startups.
4. Should you go with MySQL + PHP backend?
   I would recommend you not to because you will need the expertise to build and it is even more difficult to maintain the application. You will spend energy in places that will add very little value to your application. Instead, you can use firebase and focus on improving the UX in the front end of the application.

Note: Firebase had one shortcoming, which is that all business logic will be written in the frontend of the app. But with a recent update, they have fixed it as well. You can read this https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/03/where-does-firebase-fit-in-your-app.html

Kindly let me know if it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I'll answer your question simply, I developed an app and a website which uses the same DB, and at first, I thought that fire base was the solution, but the problem is that firebase doesn't have much flexibility, so, I used PHP with MySQL, and I developed a JSON API for my app. I think you should do the same ;)